# I want to make the button at the bottom transparent as that of Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, button, transparency

I want to make the button at the bottom transparent as that of Google Maps. My problem is when  i overlay the button over the map, some part of the map becomes invisible due to button, So i need a semi transparent button same as that of Google Maps application. Also, how can i move the default zoom controls and "Google" text in the map which exists there by default, so that while placing the button won't cover them..

Answer (score 0):

`View.setAlpha(float) / android:alpha`:- Sets the opacity of the view. This is a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely opaque.

TO make completely transparent: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

**Edit:**
Incase you need transparency with color, then you need to set background to button, in the form of `"#argb"` or `"#aarrggbb"`. where a stands for proportion of alpha.

Comment: thank you for your response but i was asking for the button like in Google Maps application. It contains grey coloured transparent buttons..